# Remaining Licenses in Company Information is in negative (-47) count

Tags: user, licenses, userlicense

In my Company profile, Remaining licenses is showing as -47.

Total Licenses available 265 and Used Licenses 312 and Remaining Licenses are -47.

How can be the remaining licenses will be negative as we can use only up to the limit. And as we paid for the limited licenses.

Comment: Did you ever have more licences available than the current figure? If the licence agreement with Salesforce changed to reduce the number of licences then it will not automatically deactivate users but show this sort of information.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds more like a question for your Account Executive at Salesforce, or possibly Salesforce support.

I'd assume you either:

1. Had more licenses in the past, and may have re-evaluated your contract with Salesforce at the start of a new Contract term, and requested a decrease in your license count. (In this case, the decreased license count wouldn't automatically de-activate any users, so your user license count may in fact be exceeding your allowed license number by a total of 47 extra users.

**OR**

2. There is a problem in your system, possibly as a result of a new purchase of licenses that didn't get added to your account correctly? Either way, in this case, the problem with your system and license count can only be fixed by escalating a ticket to the Salesforce support team.